# ListView.getItemAtPosition(i) equivalent in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-recyclerview

I'm migrating from a ListView backed by a CursorAdapter, to a RecyclerView backed by shywim's [CursorRecyclerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b).

I'm having trouble migrating this part that used to return a cursor object:

```
(MyCursor)mListView.getItemAtPosition(i)
```

How to get access to cursor at specific position inside RecyclerView? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not part of the  RecyclerView. To overcome it I define an interface:

```
  public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
  }
```

The ViewHolder implements the View.OnClickListener, and its constructor takes an object that implements my OnItemClickListener interface:

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

     public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this(itemView);
        mListener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
        }
    }
```

When you click on the row,  I forward trough the listener the view clicked and its position

Comment: If your List<model> position == your click position, you can just return the model at that position.

Comment: yes of course.. still once you have the position, you can access the model through the adapter

Comment: I have used similar solutions, I am just saying. Your solution is better because it handles all cases.

Comment: This only shows how to get the position of the holder, but doesn't explain how to get at the cursor data at that position.

Comment: The data is hold by the adapter. Ask to it