# How to implement OnSetClickListener for button in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have been having difficulties making my device register button clicks within an android recyclerview and am not sure why it is not responding as I have looked around and it seems as though it should work. But what I really want to know is if I have put stuff in the wrong place, am I missing something and if so what?

Holder Class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView time;
    public ImageButton button;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        time = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        button = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Test", "Button clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    // WIll hold the timer objects passed through
    ArrayList<Timer> lData = null;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<Timer> myDataset) {
        lData = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_adapter, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.time.setText(lData.get(position).getTime());
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lData.size();
    }

    // Gets the timers
    public ArrayList<Timer> getData() {
        return lData;
    }
}
```

Main Activity Class (OnCreate Method)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(timers);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

View Item

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:layout_margin="6dip"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_pause"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107110/listview-getitematpositioni-equivalent-in-recyclerview) helps

Comment: Your code works for me (Target SDK: 21, Nexus 4) - does Logcat behave normally on your side?

Comment: Yeah, I log when the add timer button is pressed however the logcat doesn't register anything when the pause buttons are pressed

Comment: The add timer button is located outside of the recyclerview