# Load a fragment on clicking CardView from RecyclerView

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've a `RecyclerView` and `CardView` inside it. Now what i want to do is load a simple `Fragment` on clicking the CardView. I'm not able to do that with FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager. Please give me some directions.

**My RecyclerViewAdapder and ViewHolder are ..**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] eventName;
    private String[] eventBrief;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewName, textViewBrief;
        public CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            textViewName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewBrief = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewBrief);
            final Context context = v.getContext();
            cardView = (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    EventFragment eventFragment = EventFragment.newInstance();
                    // Load and view eventFragment here??
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] eventName, String[] eventBrief) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.eventBrief = eventBrief;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_card_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewName.setText(eventName[position]);
        holder.textViewBrief.setText(eventBrief[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return eventName.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to go at this, really. I feel that the best implementation is a callback to the activity notifying that an item has been clicked. I'll give you a hand with some code, see below:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] eventName;
private String[] eventBrief;
private OnItemClickListener listener;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView textViewName, textViewBrief;
    public CardView cardView;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public ViewHolder(View v, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(v);

        textViewName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewBrief = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewBrief);
        final Context context = v.getContext();
        cardView = (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(listener!=null)
                   listener.onItemClick(textViewName.getText().toString(),
         textViewBrief.getText().toString();
            }
        });
    }
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] eventName, String[] eventBrief) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
    this.eventBrief = eventBrief;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_card_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(eventName[position]);
    holder.textViewBrief.setText(eventBrief[position]);
    holder.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventName.length;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
       public void onItemClick(String textName, String textViewBrief); 
    } 
}
```

Then in your activity just instantiate it like this:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(eventName, eventBrief);
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(String textName, String textViewBrief){
            EventFragment eventFragment = EventFragment.newInstance();
            //replace content frame with your own view.
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, eventFragment).commit()
       }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple implementation is to add a `onClickListener()` to the `ViewHolder` 's  `itemView` in the constructor of the `Adapter`.

```
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @martiendt @viper 
what is `Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();` ?

Comment: `MyFragment` is the fragment class of the fragment that you want to load @sabbibJAVA

Comment: @sabbibJAVA you can see my implementation here https://github.com/martiendt/daily-dhamma i used this on https://github.com/martiendt/daily-dhamma/blob/master/app/src/main/java/red/point/dailydhamma/ListFragment.java

Answer (score 5):

> I'm not able to do that with FragmentManager or
>   SupportFragmentManager

That's because `RecyclerViewAdapter` doesn't hold a reference to the `FragmentManager`. You should communicate to the Activity/Fragment hosting the `RecyclerView`, that the event occurred and from there you *start* the fragment. To do so check my answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107110/listview-getitematpositioni-equivalent-in-recyclerview/29107243#29107243)