# How to pass the data between RecyclerViewAdapter into details activity with onClick

Tags: android, bundle, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass the data between this `RecyclerAdapter` to DetailsActivity which is when the user clicked on each item, get the item `position` and then for example get the title from `recyclerView` and show it into `MainRecyclerDetails` `TextView`, and here is my try:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.FeedListRowHolder> {

    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        return new FeedListRowHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {

        FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);
        feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
        feedListRowHolder.date.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getDate()));
        feedListRowHolder.tags.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTags()));
        feedListRowHolder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        feedListRowHolder.title.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        feedListRowHolder.date.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        feedListRowHolder.tags.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        feedListRowHolder.thumbnail.setTag(feedListRowHolder);
        feedListRowHolder.title.setTag(feedListRowHolder);
        feedListRowHolder.date.setTag(feedListRowHolder);
        feedListRowHolder.tags.setTag(feedListRowHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FeedListRowHolder holder = (FeedListRowHolder) view.getTag();
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, feedItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainRecyclerDetails.class);

            String getrec = feedItem.getTitle();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title", getrec);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    };


    class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected ImageView thumbnail;
        protected TextView title;
        protected TextView date;
        protected TextView tags;

        public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            this.tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagsItems);
        }
    }

}
```

for getting it in `DetailsActivity`:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
```

But, it's not working.

What am i doing wrong with this?

Cheers!

Comment: where is your `OnClickListener` ? Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107110/listview-getitematpositioni-equivalent-in-recyclerview/29107243#29107243) helps

Comment: @Blackbelt - this one?:`View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: I completely missed that. What happens ? are fDetailsActivity  and  MainRecyclerDetails the same activity ?

Comment: @Blackbelt - no, i just edit the question and fix this mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this way

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.FeedListRowHolder> {

    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        return new FeedListRowHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
        FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);
        feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
        feedListRowHolder.date.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getDate()));
        feedListRowHolder.tags.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTags()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }

    class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        protected ImageView thumbnail;
        protected TextView title;
        protected TextView date;
        protected TextView tags;

        public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            this.tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagsItems);

            thumbnail.setOnClickListener(this);
            title.setOnClickListener(this);
            date.setOnClickListener(this);
            tags.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, feedItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainRecyclerDetails.class);
            String getrec = feedItem.getTitle();
            i.putExtra("title", getrec);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

in your MainRecyclerDetails activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title = extra.getString("title");
}
```

Comment: nx steven, but still this line startActivity(i); doesn't work, should i use another way for pass the data? i just need to show each item details on that activity...

Comment: you can try putExtra method in Intent object, see my edited code